# iOS where should I download and store index.html

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, webview, uiwebview

I want to download a Javascript/Html5 code in zip format and then unzip the code and load the index.html file in webview in iOS.

So where should I save this zip folder on iPhone ? Document Directory or cached Directory ?

Answer (score 0):

All data that can be downloaded again most correct be stored in cached Directory. Files stored in Document folder will be synchronized with iCloud. See [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html). In your case, I think you need to store in cached.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: I think this statement is incorrect `"All data that can be downloaded again **must** be stored in cached Directory."` I have apps that download data and it doesn't get stored in the cached directory, there is nothing to say it **MUST**.

Comment: I'd still say **should** is incorrect. I'm having a look through the documentation that you have provided in your answer and there is no you should do this or you must do this. You're probably best reading the section title **Where You Should Put Your App’s Files** it might give you a better understanding

Comment: Thanks you, you are right. I know examples where Apple has banned app because it takes a lot of space on iCloud. (Download videos and save in a document folder)

Comment: How can I load webview from Document directory?

Answer (score 0):

Better store it in document directory since your file should be available always.In Cache directory,you should store only those files which can be recreated easily. System may delete content of this directory (to free up the disk space) when it is required.